# "Men we don't like it" or "We men don't like it"?

Tags: grammar

Can you tell me which one(s) is/are correct, please?

a. We men don't like it.

b. Men we don't like it.

C. Us men don't like it.

d. Men us don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, you're looking to express the idea that:

> Our group, the one containing the set of human beings who are male, do not like it (whatever *it* may be).

OK, **b** and **d** are definitely out. They are ungrammatical and downright barbaric.

That leaves **a** and **c**. While **a** is the up-register (formal) way of stating the proposition, **c** is very often how native speakers of English actually express the idea. If you're in a formal situation where people will think less of you if they think you have sloppy grammar, use **a**. If you're drinking in a bar with friends, **c** will sound more natural.

Comment: "*Us men don't like it.*": can 'us' be the subject?

Comment: @dan: Nope. It would be a compound subject, "us" modifying "men".

Comment: It looks very unusual to me. It's really the first time I see this. Do you know if any grammar guide to support 'us men' as a subject? Thanks!

Comment: It would be non-standard, but that's often how people talk.

Comment: Is it regional? Is it used in the US, Britain, or other English speaking countries?

Comment: I've heard it all over North America, England, and Ireland. Don't recall Scotland or Wales, but I think it likely. Note that it'd be standard in the propositional case: "For us men, it was a real surprise."

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense to me. Thanks for all your input!

Comment: "Prepositional" case ... haha, stupid tiny keyboard.

Comment: Can we also say "Me man doesn't like it", "Them men don't like it", "Him man doesn't like it", "Her woman doesn't like it", or "Them women doesn't like it"?

Comment: Some of those are non-standard, some are downright awful, some are never ever heard outside of pidgin English.

Comment: Can you help to identify which one(s) is widely used by native speakers? Besides 'Us men  don't like it'.

Comment: I dare not use "Us men don't like it" :-)